# Calculate a complex difference score with tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a large dataset of 70 000 rows that I want to perform some operations on, but I can't find an appropriate solution.

```
     bib sta run course finish comment day
1    42   9   1     SG  19.88      99   1
2    42  17   2      A  19.96      11   1
3    42  27   3      B  20.92      22   1
4    42  39   4      A  19.60      11   1
5    42  48   5     SG  20.24      99   1
6    42  61   6      C  22.90      33   1
7    42  76   7      B  20.70      22   1
8    42  86   8      C  22.74      33   1
9    42  93   9      C  22.75      33   1
10   42 103  10      A  19.79      11   1
11   42 114  11      B  20.67      22   1
12   42 120  12     SG  20.10      99   1
```

I want to end up with a tibble that:

1. calculates the mean finish time in SG course for each bib number on one particular day. For example, 19.88 + 20.24 + 20.10 / 3
2. calculate a difference score for each observation in the dataset by subtracting finish from this mean SG score. For example, 19.88 - mean(SG), 19.96 - mean(SG).

I have tried the following approach:

1. First group by day, bib and course. Then filter by SG and calculate the mean:

```
avg.sgtime <- df %>%
  group_by(day, bib, course) %>%
  filter(course == 'SG') %>%
  mutate(avg.sg = mean(finish))
```

Resulting in the following tibble

```
 bib   sta   run course finish comment day   avg.sg
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>   <dbl>   <int> <chr>  <dbl>
 1    42     9     1 SG       19.9      99 1       20.1
 2    42    48     5 SG       20.2      99 1       20.1
 3    42   120    12 SG       20.1      99 1       20.1
 4    42     6     1 SG       20.0      99 2       19.9
 5    42    42     5 SG       19.8      77 2       19.9
 6    42   130    15 SG       19.9      99 2       19.9
 7    42     6     1 SG       20.6      99 3       20.5
 8    42    68    12 SG       20.6      77 3       20.5
 9    42    90    15 SG       20.4      77 3       20.5
```

Finally I join the two tibbles together using the following syntax:

```
df %>% full_join(avg.sgtime) %>%
  mutate(diff = finish - avg.sg)
```

However, this doesn't work. It only works for the SG course but not for course A, B and C. Is there a way to fix this or is there a better solution to the problem?

```
bib sta run course finish comment day   avg.sg         diff
1    42   9   1     SG  19.88      99   1 20.07333 -0.193333333
2    42  17   2      A  19.96      11   1       NA           NA
3    42  27   3      B  20.92      22   1       NA           NA
4    42  39   4      A  19.60      11   1       NA           NA
5    42  48   5     SG  20.24      99   1 20.07333  0.166666667
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your values for `finish` within the `mutate()` and calculate the mean based on those:

```
df %>%
  group_by(day,bib) %>%
  mutate(
    avg.sg = mean(finish[course=="SG"]),
    diff = finish - avg.sg)
```

Comment: Oh, this is definetelly the "right" answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what you are aiming for?

(note that I added a few random values for a second `bib` just to make sure the join is done properly)

The difference to your attempt is using `summarise()` instead of `mutate()` to consolidate the avg.sgtime data frame, and also dropping a few columns so that the `join` is not populated with `NA`s. Instead of dropping you can also set the relevant columns to join by passing the `by` argument to the `left_join()` function.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # for join

avg.sgtime <- df %>%
  group_by(day, bib, course) %>%
  filter(course == 'SG') %>%
  summarise(avg.sg = mean(finish), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(c(bib, day, avg.sg))

avg.sgtime
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>     bib   day avg.sg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1    42     1   20.1
#> 2    43     1   19.1
#> 3    44     2   19.3
df %>% left_join(avg.sgtime) %>%
  mutate(diff = finish - avg.sg)
#> Joining, by = c("bib", "day")
#> # A tibble: 36 x 9
#>      bib   sta   run course finish comment   day avg.sg   diff
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1    42     9     1 SG       19.9      99     1   20.1 -0.193
#>  2    42    17     2 A        20.0      11     1   20.1 -0.113
#>  3    42    27     3 B        20.9      22     1   20.1  0.847
#>  4    42    39     4 A        19.6      11     1   20.1 -0.473
#>  5    42    48     5 SG       20.2      99     1   20.1  0.167
#>  6    42    61     6 C        22.9      33     1   20.1  2.83 
#>  7    42    76     7 B        20.7      22     1   20.1  0.627
#>  8    42    86     8 C        22.7      33     1   20.1  2.67 
#>  9    42    93     9 C        22.8      33     1   20.1  2.68 
#> 10    42   103    10 A        19.8      11     1   20.1 -0.283
#> # … with 26 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

### data

```r
df <- tribble(~bib, ~sta, ~run, ~course, ~finish, ~comment, ~day,
              42,     9,     1,       "SG",    19.88,        99,     1,
              42,    17,     2,        "A",    19.96,        11,     1,
              42,    27,     3,        "B",    20.92,        22,     1,
              42,    39,     4,        "A",    19.60,        11,     1,
              42,    48,     5,       "SG",    20.24,        99,     1,
              42,    61,     6,        "C",    22.90,        33,     1,
              42,    76,     7,        "B",    20.70,        22,     1,
              42,    86,     8,        "C",    22.74,        33,     1,
              42,    93,     9,        "C",    22.75,        33,     1,
              42,   103,    10,        "A",    19.79,        11,     1,
              42,   114,    11,        "B",    20.67,        22,     1,
              42,   120,    12,       "SG",    20.10,        99,     1,
              
              43,     9,     1,       "SG",    19.12,        99,     1,
              43,    17,     2,        "A",    19.64,        11,     1,
              43,    27,     3,        "B",    20.62,        22,     1,
              43,    39,     4,        "A",    19.23,        11,     1,
              43,    48,     5,       "SG",    20.11,        99,     1,
              43,    61,     6,        "C",    22.22,        33,     1,
              43,    76,     7,        "B",    20.33,        22,     1,
              43,    86,     8,        "C",    22.51,        33,     1,
              43,    93,     9,        "C",    22.78,        33,     1,
              43,   103,    10,        "A",    19.98,        11,     1,
              43,   114,    11,        "B",    20.11,        22,     1,
              43,   120,    12,       "SG",    18.21,        99,     1,
              
              44,     9,     1,       "SG",    19.18,        99,     2,
              44,    17,     2,        "A",    19.56,        11,     2,
              44,    27,     3,        "B",    20.62,        22,     2,
              44,    39,     4,        "A",    19.20,        11,     2,
              44,    48,     5,       "SG",    20.74,        99,     2,
              44,    61,     6,        "C",    22.50,        33,     2,
              44,    76,     7,        "B",    20.60,        22,     2,
              44,    86,     8,        "C",    22.74,        33,     2,
              44,    93,     9,        "C",    22.85,        33,     2,
              44,   103,    10,        "A",    19.59,        11,     2,
              44,   114,    11,        "B",    20.27,        22,     2,
              44,   120,    12,       "SG",    18.10,        99,     2,
              )
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly. How does  .groups = "drop" work?

Comment: In general, grouping a data.frame does not modify the data but modifies how other verbs (mutate, summarise, etc)  will modify the actual data. The grouping variables, per default, kept in the resulting frame. You can change this behaviour by using .groups="drop". See `?summarise` for more details.

Comment: in any case, isn't the answer of Michael Barrowman much simpler? or does it not work as expected?

Comment: Yes that worked. All solutions worked. I agree, Barrowman's solution was the most readable

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks** @Marcelo Avila for providing me with a very good hint:

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(bib, day) %>%
  mutate(across(finish, ~ mean(.x[course == "SG"]), .names = "avg_{.col}"),
         diff = finish - avg_finish, 
         avg_finish = ifelse(course == "SG", avg_finish, NA))


# A tibble: 12 x 9
# Groups:   bib, day [1]
     bib   sta   run course finish comment   day avg_finish    diff
   <int> <int> <int> <chr>   <dbl>   <int> <int>      <dbl>   <dbl>
 1    42     9     1 SG       19.9      99     1       20.1 -0.193 
 2    42    17     2 A        20.0      11     1       NA   -0.113 
 3    42    27     3 B        20.9      22     1       NA    0.847 
 4    42    39     4 A        19.6      11     1       NA   -0.473 
 5    42    48     5 SG       20.2      99     1       20.1  0.167 
 6    42    61     6 C        22.9      33     1       NA    2.83  
 7    42    76     7 B        20.7      22     1       NA    0.627 
 8    42    86     8 C        22.7      33     1       NA    2.67  
 9    42    93     9 C        22.8      33     1       NA    2.68  
10    42   103    10 A        19.8      11     1       NA   -0.283 
11    42   114    11 B        20.7      22     1       NA    0.597 
12    42   120    12 SG       20.1      99     1       20.1  0.0267
```

I also added another alternative solution with a minor change, using dear @Marcelo Avila's data set:

```
df %>%
  group_by(bib, day) %>%
  mutate(across(finish, ~ mean(.x[select(cur_data(), course) == "SG"]), .names = "avg_{.col}"),
         diff = finish - avg_finish, 
         avg_finish = ifelse(course == "SG", avg_finish, NA))

# A tibble: 36 x 9
# Groups:   bib, day [3]
     bib   sta   run course finish comment   day avg_finish   diff
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1    42     9     1 SG       19.9      99     1       20.1 -0.193
 2    42    17     2 A        20.0      11     1       NA   -0.113
 3    42    27     3 B        20.9      22     1       NA    0.847
 4    42    39     4 A        19.6      11     1       NA   -0.473
 5    42    48     5 SG       20.2      99     1       20.1  0.167
 6    42    61     6 C        22.9      33     1       NA    2.83 
 7    42    76     7 B        20.7      22     1       NA    0.627
 8    42    86     8 C        22.7      33     1       NA    2.67 
 9    42    93     9 C        22.8      33     1       NA    2.68 
10    42   103    10 A        19.8      11     1       NA   -0.283
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Comment: this is a more elegant solution than mine. I tried to avoid joining but didn't think of this approach. However, this didn't run correctly with the `df` I generated in my answer (included more days and bibs). Could you please test with that data as well?

Comment: Apparently,  using  `mean(.x[course == "SG"])` instead of `mean(.x[df$course == "SG"])` works. Any reason to use df$course instead of `course` directly? --- Or adding na.rm = TRUE, to `mean()` would work as well.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @MarceloAvila, yes you are right. I was suspicious about `df$course` as it seemingly uses the entire `course` variable regardless of grouping as it does not take grouping into account. I also added another alternative more suited to tidyverse with an emphasis on `course` values within each group.

Comment: First argument in `across` is `.cols` where you choose the column you would like to apply your function on. here I chose `finish` as required by the question. He we use a lamba style formula consisting of `~` and `mean(.x)` instead of `function(x) mean(x)`. So `.x` here refers to our selected column `finish` and among all its values I chose those whose corresponding `course` value is equal to `SG`. The second solution is more clear.